# Which words to capitalize in Master thesis headings?

Tags: capitalization, heading

I'm writing my Master thesis in English and now I do not know about the headings. Do I have to write heading in upper or only lower case printing?

For example:

> 1. Processing and Distribution Server
> 2. Indoor Navigation and Positioning App

or

> 1. Processing and distribution server
> 2. Indoor navigation and positioning app

Which version is correct and can also be used in presentation slides?

Comment: See [writers.se] & [academia.se]

Comment: There is no one can ask you for a certain format without providing a template or guidelines. If there is no such thing in your college, do whatever you like it. NO ONE can blame you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a matter of style. Read: these conventions can vary within fields and even subfields. So you are best advised to consult your peers, faculty members, or just your supervisor. Failing that, look at other papers in your particular field before deciding anything definitively. And if there is no clear pattern to make out, go with whichever variant strikes your fancy — just make sure to be consistent. Pick one style and stick to it throughout.